# Getting a Dynamic $_POST

Tags: php

I am having trouble getting dynamic posts.  Is there something wrong here?

```
echo $_POST['$question_id'];
```

Gives me nothing even when $question_id = 1, var_dump($_POST) shows values for numbers 1-17.

```
 array(18) { [1]=> string(1) "A" [2]=> string(1) "A" [3]=> string(1) "A" [4]=> string(1) "A" [5]=> string(1) "A" [6]=> string(1) "A" [7]=> string(1) "A" [8]=> string(1) "A" [9]=> string(1) "A" [10]=> string(1) "A" [11]=> string(1) "A" [12]=> string(1) "A" [13]=> string(1) "A" [14]=> string(1) "A" [15]=> string(1) "A" [16]=> string(1) "A" [17]=> string(1) "B" ["now"]=> string(8) "".$now."" }
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `$_POST['question_id'];`

Comment: variables inside single quotes are not interpreted to the variable's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for single quotes :

```
echo $_POST[$question_id];
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

variables inside single quotes are not interpreted to the variable's value but instead are treated as the literal string. Use double quotes or just remove the quotes.

So this:

```
echo $_POST['$question_id'];
```

Should be:

```
echo $_POST[$question_id];
```

or even this would work (though IMHO is slightly ugly):

```
echo $_POST["$question_id"];
```